# Сортировка строк матрицы по возрастанию элементов первого, второго и тд столбцов

Tags: c, сортировка, матрицы

Необходимо отсортировать строки матрицы по возрастанию элементов первого столбца матрицы, причем, если находятся два равных элемента первого столбца, то отсортировать их по второму столбцу и тд.

Пример исходной матрицы:

```
2 3 4 5
2 1 5 6
2 1 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Отсортированная матрица:

```
1 2 3 4
2 1 3 4
2 1 5 6
2 3 4 5
```

Прототип функции сортировки `sortMatrix(int** array, int row, int column)`

Comment: Что вы сделали для того, чтобы решить эту задачу?

Comment: @retorta, ну если учитывать что язык си, а не c++, то вопрос не такой уж и тривиальный. В c++, конечно, просто складываем всё в вектор векторов и вызываем `std::sort`, который заюзает стандартный компаратор. Хотя ваш вопрос остаётся в силе)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь может помочь функция [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). Также вам нужно будет написать собственный компаратор. Так как в си нету лямбда функций, а мы, конечно, хотим, чтобы наша функция была потокобезопасной, то нам также потребуется глобальная [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thread_local) переменная. Возможная реализация:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

thread_local int column_;

int comparator(const void *element1, const void *element2) {
    int *line1 = (int *) element1;
    int *line2 = (int *) element2;
    for (int j = 0; j < column_; ++j) {
        if (line1[j] != line2[j]) {
            return line2[j] - line1[j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void sortMatrix(int **array, int row, int column) {
    column_ = column;
    qsort(array, (size_t) row, sizeof(int *), comparator);
}

int main() {
    int row = 4;
    int column = 4;

//  этот массив нужен только для удобства инициализации основного массива
    int arrayOnStack[4][4] = {
            {2, 3, 4, 5},
            {2, 1, 5, 6},
            {2, 1, 3, 4},
            {1, 2, 3, 4}
    };

    int **array = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * row);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        array[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * column);
        for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j) {
            array[i][j] = arrayOnStack[i][j];
        }
    }

    printf("До сортировки:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j) {
            printf("%d%c", array[i][j], " \n"[j == column - 1]);
        }
    }

    sortMatrix((int **) array, row, column);

    printf("\n");
    printf("После сортировки:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j) {
            printf("%d%c", array[i][j], " \n"[j == column - 1]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Возможный вывод:

```
До сортировки:
2 3 4 5
2 1 5 6
2 1 3 4
1 2 3 4

После сортировки:
1 2 3 4
2 1 3 4
2 1 5 6
2 3 4 5
```

Код на [ideone](http://ideone.com/Nbe7ly). К сожалению, там не потокобезопасная реализация, зато для си компилируется!

Comment: Вероятно, стоит избавиться от new — си всё таки. Как на счёт массива прямо на стеке?

Comment: @mymedia, исправил. С двумерным массивом на стеке функция не будет работать, всё-таки он [не является](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4409663/5812238) `int**`.

Comment: Ну, тогда надо избавиться и от `for (int i...`.

Comment: Почему? В си вроде есть `for`.

Comment: @0andriy, алло, уже не то чтобы С99 на дворе, уже С11 давно актуален. Переменные лет двадцать уже можно где попало объявлять.

Comment: Во-первых, следите за речью, во-вторых, где-попало -- это плохой стиль в Си.